# Finding $J'(0)$ and $J''(0)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The Bessel function of order $0$, $y= J(x)$, satisfies
$$0 = xy'' + y' + xy$$
for all values of $x$. $J(0) = 1$.

a) Find $J'(0)$.
b) Find $J''(0)$.

SOLUTION:
a) $J'(0) = 0$.
b) $J''(0) = -1/2$

Unsure of how my prof came up with these answers, could someone please show me the steps they took to arrive at them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $x = 0$ directly into the equation

$$x J''(x) + J'(x) + x J(x) = 0$$
to find $J'(0) = 0$. Differentiate once and evaluate at $x = 0$ to find $J''(0)$. The initial condition $J(0)  = 1$ will be used in the term that comes from $(x J)'$.